# Migrating to cakephp 2.x - update list

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to move my project from cakephp 1.3 to cakephp 2.x. I know it is overdue. But I never got around to it. I have a few components, I would like to continue using in cakephp 2.x. I was wondering what are things I need to update in component. I am trying to build a list of things I need to update before moving it to cakephp 2.0

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not going along with the very good documentation on this?

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html + 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-1-migration-guide.html + 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-2-migration-guide.html + 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-3-migration-guide.html

the build in upgrade shell can assist on this

PS: also, this has been asked a lot before

you can also use my Upgrade Shell to fix most of those things automatically, if possible:
https://github.com/dereuromark/upgrade

it also fixes tons of other things that are not necessary but recommended or helpful.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Your Upgrade Shell is awesome. I have only one problem about plugin. It did not change my plugin's component. How to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry My bad. found -p plugin name later. Should I rename vendors in Plugin folder to Vendor. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Yes, they are now named "Vendor"